# How to pan down a view controller in storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard, xcode-storyboard

I'm using a scroll view in the storyboard for one of my view controllers and I would like to know if there is a way to move the current view of the view controller down so that I can add things below.

I've seen that when tapping on CollectionView (which is at the bottom of my screen and extends below the view), the view on my viewcontroller seems to move down a bit to reveal more of the CollectionView, but not entirely. Is there a way that I can make the view go lower?

Answer (score 0):

Change the size of viewController as shown in the image below: 
[image]